# How does one initialize/move a camera in a SpriteKit program using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, sprite-kit, draggable

I have a map and it's bigger than the device's screen size, so I want the user to be able to navigate around the map by dragging the screen, similar to Clash of Clans.

How can I create a camera view so I can drag the camera around the map?

Also, how can I customize where the camera's center begins as the scene switches to the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

theres no camera in swift.  the idea is you add your background to a "world node"

```
// set up stuff you want to add to world node
let bg = SKSpriteNode(... initializer  

// make a "worldNode" that you move around
self.worldNode = SKNode()

// add your bg to the worldNode
worldNode.addChild(bg)

// add worldNode to the scene
self.addChild(worldNode)
```

ok so now you have that.. now you make some method to move the world around depending on a position

```
func centerViewOn(centerOn: CGPoint) { 
    self.worldNode.position = CGPoint(x: -x, y: -y)
}
```

You pass in the players position, and the worldNode will move.  That's the general idea.

You probably need to add some conditional stuff in here so that the camera doesn't move too far.  With this code, the camera has no limit, and can look past the edge of your game world.  You'd want to limit it so it stops following the player when they reach the edge.

Comment: What do you put in the "(... initializer"?

Comment: whatever you want.. you can make an SKSpriteNode using an image, a texture atlas, you can make one just using a color and a size.  It depends on what you're trying to do.   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html

look at initializing a new sprite

Comment: When I try to add the world node using the code "self.world = SKNode()", Xcode tells me that my GameScene does not have a member called 'world'. How do I initialize the node to my scene?

Comment: you can remove that line, and at the top of your scene you add a property.  
let worldNode = SKNode()